# Direct login on facebook from android app?

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I want to realize a simple login in on facebook. I have a button "Facebook connect" and when I press this button I want to open the facebook login page, and after introducing the email and password to sign in on facebook. I have seen the examples from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/ but I can't realize how should I do this. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this tutorial [here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-1), it will show you how to set it all up and is easy to follow. Hope this helps.